# Question about permutation and series (are permutation always finite ? what are their impact on series ?)

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sigma :\mathbb N\longrightarrow \mathbb N$. We denote the support of $\sigma $ by $$supp(\sigma )=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid \sigma (n)\neq n\}.$$

**Q1)** Is the support always finite ? i.e. is for example $$\sigma (k)=\begin{cases}k+1&k\in2\mathbb N\\ k-1&k\in2\mathbb N+1\end{cases},$$
consider as a permutation ?

I heard that not, so I want to be sure.

**Q2)** I know that if a series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}u_n$ is not absolument convergent, then for all permutation $\sigma $ we have that $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}u_n\neq \sum_{n\in\mathbb N}u_{\sigma (n)}.$$

Is it really for all permutation ? For example, if I take $\sigma =(12345)$ (or even $\sigma =(12)$), will we really have $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\neq \sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\frac{(-1)^{\sigma (n)}}{\sigma (n)}\ \ ?$$

I know that we can regroup terms to get that the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ divergent, but if $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\frac{(-1)^{\sigma (n)}}{\sigma (n)}$ is convergent and $supp(\sigma )$ finite, will we really have $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\frac{(-1)^{\sigma (n)}}{\sigma (n)}\neq \sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\ \ \ ?$$

**Q3)** Same question if $supp(\sigma )$ is infinite (if it's possible) and $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N^*}\frac{(-1)^{\sigma (n)}}{\sigma (n)}$ convergent.

I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

If $supp(\sigma )$ is finite (and the series convergent but not absolutely convergent), you will always have $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_{\sigma (n)}.$$

Indeed, let $M=\max supp(\sigma )$. Then,

$$\sum_{n=1}^M u_n=\sum_{n=1}^M u_{\sigma (n)}.$$

Since $u_n=u_{\sigma (n)}$ for all $n>M$, the claim follow.

**Edit**

If $|supp(\sigma )|=+\infty $, you can't say anything a priori. For example with $u_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ and the permutation $\sigma =(12)(34)(56)(78)...$ the sum will not change, whereas if you take the permutation that group even and odd $n$, the sum will not converge. After there is other combinaison that will change the sum.

Comment: Nice, it's what I wanted to know. And if $supp(\sigma )$ is infinite ? Will we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n\neq \sum_{n=1}^\infty u_{\sigma (n)}$ ? Or we can have equality ?

Comment: I edited my answer